# how to determine a user's current working directory (install4j)

Tags: install4j

Is there a way to determine what directory the user is in when he/she launches the installer?

I need to leave some files there.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: System.getProperty("user.dir") comes close.  It produces the temporary directory created by install4j that is a subdirectory of the user's starting directory [on linux -- haven't tried windows].

Comment: Just finding the parent of user.dir does not work because install4j sometimes changes it. For example, when user.dir/.. is not writable, the install4j temporary directory is placed in /tmp.

Comment: I think I found the answer: System.getProperty("install4j.cwd")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an installer variable use

```
${installer:sys.mediaDir}
```

In a script, call

```
context.getVariable("sys.mediaDir")
```

Comment: Ingo, this is close, but not what I want.  The user can start an installer (located in sys.mediaDir) from anywhere.  Is there any reason I should not use install4j.cwd?  Thanks.

Comment: OK, I thought the files are next to the installer, as it's often the case on a DVD. The working directory is only changed on Linux/Unix, and it's indeed the system property install4j.cwd that contains the original working directory in that case.